# How do I pass a array of structures to a function as a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, graph

I have done the following program, to input a graph and color it in at most 6 colors (given degree at most 5 etc.)

Most of the code is self explanatory, with comments to explain what each line does.

I have included my code below and the errors that are raised, but I'm especially curious whats causing the warning saying the parameter I've input isn't of expected type. This has become sort of a recurring error for me, and I'd love some feedback!

Any suggestions on the code itself would be appreciated too, but my main issue at the moment is related to the passing of parameters

```
struct NODE{
    int node_no;
    char color;
};

char Colors[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

// l->left index, right index is fixed at n-1, as we colors from  0 to n-1
void ColorTree(struct NODE *Tree[], int l, int n, int Edges [][2], int e)
{
    if(n==1)    // if only one node, color node with lowest color
    {
        Tree[0]->color='a';
    }
    
    int i,j; char used_colors[6], c='N';
    
    for(i=0;i<=e;i++)   // colors 
    {
        if(Edges[i][0] == Tree[l]->node_no)
        {
            c=Tree[Edges[i][1]]->color;
            continue;
        }
        if(Edges[i][1] == Tree[l]->node_no)
        {
            c=Tree[Edges[i][0]]->color;
        }

        for(j=0;used_colors[j]!='\0';j++);  // finds empty position of used_colors
        if(c!='N')
            used_colors[j]=c;   // if the color is not N, add to already used colors
    }

    for(i=0;Colors[i]!='\0';i++)
        for(j=0;used_colors[j]!='\0';j++)
        {   
            if(Colors[i]==used_colors[j])   // the color is already used
                continue;
            else if(used_colors[j+1]=='\0')     // the color is not used
                break;
        }

    Tree[l]->color=Colors[i];   // the unused color being assigned to Tree[l]

    if(l==(n-1))    // all nodes have been colored
        return;

    ColorTree(&Tree,l+1,(n-1),Edges, e);
}

int main()
{     
    int n,e,i;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    struct NODE Tree[n];    // n-> no. of vertices 

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)     // initialising the tree, with node 0,1,2...n-1 and  color = 'N'
    {
        Tree[i].node_no=i;
        Tree[i].color='N';    // 'N'->no color
    }

    scanf("%d", &e);    // e-> no.of edges

    int Edges[e][2];
    
    for(i=0;i<e;i++)    // entering the edges
    {
        scanf("%d", &Edges[i][0]);
        scanf("%d", &Edges[i][1]);
    }

    ColorTree(&Tree,0,(n-1),Edges,e);

    printf("%c", Tree[0].color);    // printing the colors in the graph
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n%c", Tree[i].color);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The errors i'm getting are:

```
<file_name>.c:51:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ColorTree’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   51 |     ColorTree(&Tree,l+1,(n-1),Edges, e);
      |               ^~~~~
      |               |
      |               struct NODE ***
<file_name>.c:11:29: note: expected ‘struct NODE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct NODE ***’
   11 | void ColorTree(struct NODE *Tree[], int l, int n, int Edges [][2], int e)
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<file_name>.c: In function ‘main’:
<file_name>.c:77:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘ColorTree’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   77 |     ColorTree(&Tree,0,(n-1),Edges,e);
      |               ^~~~~
      |               |
      |               struct NODE (*)[(sizetype)(n)]
<file_name>.c:11:29: note: expected ‘struct NODE **’ but argument is of type ‘struct NODE (*)[(sizetype)(n)]’
   11 | void ColorTree(struct NODE *Tree[], int l, int n, int Edges [][2], int e)
      |
```

My program eventually terminates through Segmentation fault after the inputs.
What am I doing wrong in passing the array of structures as reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation expects a `NODE` pointer array (e.g. an array of `NODE*`). In reality, your passing it `&Tree` from `main()`, which is *not* `NODE` pointer array, its the address of a hard array. Worse (if there is such a thing), in `ColorTree` you're pouring more salt on the wound by recursing with `&Tree`, in that context, `&Tree` is actually `NODE ***`

None of this needs to be done this way. Simply passing `Tree` in both calling scenarios and changing the formal argument to `NODE *Tree` (or `NODE Tree[]`), and fixing all the code therein will work. An example is below (that utilizes dynamic allocations because my C compiler is dumber than bag of hammers and doesn't understand VLAs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct NODE {
    int node_no;
    char color;
};

char Colors[6] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f' };

// l->left index, right index is fixed at n-1, as we colors from  0 to n-1
void ColorTree(struct NODE Tree[], int l, int n, int Edges[][2], int e)
{
    if (n == 1)    // if only one node, color node with lowest color
    {
        Tree[0].color = 'a';
    }

    int i, j; char used_colors[6], c = 'N';

    for (i = 0; i < e; i++)   // colors 
    {
        if (Edges[i][0] == Tree[l].node_no)
        {
            c = Tree[Edges[i][1]].color;
            continue;
        }
        if (Edges[i][1] == Tree[l].node_no)
        {
            c = Tree[Edges[i][0]].color;
        }

        for (j = 0; used_colors[j] != '\0'; j++);  // finds empty position of used_colors
        if (c != 'N')
            used_colors[j] = c;   // if the color is not N, add to already used colors
    }

    for (i = 0; Colors[i] != '\0'; i++)
        for (j = 0; used_colors[j] != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if (Colors[i] == used_colors[j])   // the color is already used
                continue;
            else if (used_colors[j + 1] == '\0')     // the color is not used
                break;
        }

    Tree[l].color = Colors[i];   // the unused color being assigned to Tree[l]

    if (l == (n - 1))    // all nodes have been colored
        return;

    ColorTree(Tree, l + 1, (n - 1), Edges, e);
}

int main()
{
    int n, e, i;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct NODE *Tree = malloc(n * sizeof *Tree);

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)     // initialising the tree, with node 0,1,2...n-1 and  color = 'N'
    {
        Tree[i].node_no = i;
        Tree[i].color = 'N';    // 'N'->no color
    }

    scanf("%d", &e);    // e-> no.of edges

    int(*Edges)[2] = malloc(e * sizeof *Edges);

    for (i = 0; i<e; i++)    // entering the edges
    {
        scanf("%d", &Edges[i][0]);
        scanf("%d", &Edges[i][1]);
    }

    ColorTree(Tree, 0, (n - 1), Edges, e);

    printf("%c", Tree[0].color);    // printing the colors in the graph
    for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
        printf("\n%c", Tree[i].color);

    return 0;
}
```

Whether this solves every issue you code faces beyond the stated question isn't guaranteed (for all I know it could be chock full of logic errors), but it will fix the problem(s) mentioned. I did, however, take liberty to fix the blatant overreach of the for-loop in ColorTree.

Comment: Oh cool, this works. Now I'm just stuck with the segmentation fault.

Comment: But thank you so much for this though! I couldn't find any proper resources online for this thanks a lot

Comment: @VargheseGeorge check your loop limits. I pointed out in my answer that the for-loop in `ColorTree` was overreaching the declared size of `Edges`. Make sure that is no longer the case in your code as it address in the answer here. And fyi, you should post the input data you're testing with as part of your question. It helps tremendously in replicating your conditions precisely.

Comment: Yeah, changed that too. Turns out I have a couple of other logical errors too. It's just a program that enters no of vertices, no of edges, and then a list of edges in the graph, colors the graph and outputs colors. Teachers don't really give us much resources so we're left figuring everything else out :)) Thank you for your answer!